# Running maths over an entire database and ranking all users

Tags: sql

I have a database of `bets`. Each bet has a 'Win', 'Loss', or 'Pending' state. What I want to do is to have an SQL statement that will get the last, say, 20 bets a user has placed, find out their ROI (Total profit / Total staked * 100).

So I'm just wondering if there is a better way to do this. Do I basically have to get the `users` table, loop over every user, get their last 20 bets, find the ROI and then order it. If my User table gets huge then this process is going to take ages, right?

Is creating a 'View' going to save on this time?

Is there a way to do this in one statement that won't cost my life in processing time?

Here are the tables
Users

```
| ID | User  | 
| 1  | Test1 |
| 2  | Test2 |
| 3  | Test3 |
| 4  | Test4 |
```

Bets

```
| ID | User | Amount | Odds | Result  |
| 1  |  1   | 10     | 1.35 | Win     |
| 2  |  1   | 25     | 2.55 | Win     |
| 3  |  3   | 15     | 1.65 | Loss    |
| 4  |  2   | 11     | 2.12 | Pending |
```

Se essentially I would like a table that ranks them as ROI.

```
| User | AmountBet | AmountWon | ROI  |
|  1   | 35        | 77        | 215  |
|  2   | 11        | 0         | 0    |
|  3   | 15        | 0         | 0    |
|  4   | 0         | 0         | 0    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ID of the bets table represents increasing time such that it can be used to identify "last 20", then

```
WITH b
AS
(
SELECT id,
       user,
       CASE WHEN result = 'Pending' THEN 0 ELSE amount END AS amount,
       CASE WHEN result = 'Win' THEN amount * odds ELSE 0 END as winnings,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY id DESC) AS rownum
FROM bets
)
SELECT user,
       SUM(amount) AS amount_bet,
       SUM(winnings) AS amount_won,
       CASE 
           WHEN SUM(amount) > 0 
           THEN SUM(winnings) * 100 / SUM(amount) 
           ELSE 0 
       END AS roi
FROM b
WHERE rownum < 21
GROUP BY user;
```

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9be36aa5371454ba75c0e53abd54d918)

Comment: Any reason why the `WITH` says `With is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting...`. Sorry maybe I omitted something that was needed to know. I'm not 100% experienced with SQL

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, just put a semi-colon immediately before the word `WITH`

Comment: Or more correctly, immediately after the previous statement.

Comment: Indeed, quite and well said.

Comment: It just says the same but with `;` now. I am using MySQL workbench and AWS if that helps.

Comment: Ah ok. Please edit your post adding the full script that's throwing the error and tag the post with MySQL.

Comment: There was a missing comma after `as winnings`. I've added it.

Comment: One alst thing. I mentioned performance. If my users and bets DB's grow will it start being really slow, or do I have thousands of rows before that happens?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem for performance. If you get into the tens or hundreds of thousands, you might consider adding an index on bets.user and bets.id (though you should probably have one already for the latter). Good luck!